# importing files from different directories

Tags: python, module, package

*I have the folder structure as follows:*

```
project1/app1/app1.py
project1/app2/app2.py
```

*I want to import app1.py to app2.py
I have tried:*

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'project1/app1')
from app1 import a1
```

*It worked fine but i dont want to hardcode the path. Inshort I dont want to use sys to import path.
I want something like this:*

```
from app1.app1 import a1
```

*Please give me some sort of advice. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: You might want to read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: is `project1` a `package`? Please include empty `__init__.py` in `project1` to make it as package

Comment: I have already added __init__.py in project1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
prj/
├── project1/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app1/
│       └── app1.py
│
└── project2/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── app2/
        └── app2.py
```

This makes project1 and project2 folder to packages

```
app1.py
greet = "Hello"

app2.py
from ...prj1.app1.app1 import *
print(greet)

Output
D:\code>>python -m prj.prj2.app2.app2
HI
```

As these are packages and need to be loaded, they should be run from prj folder level with -m flag

Comment: @Bitswazsky thanks for the edit. Just wanted to know how did you structure the prj, have you used any online formatter or code snippet to organize?

Comment: On mac terminal I use `tree <foldername>` to get this kinda structures. Should be available on linux terminal as well.